# ASA 5505 - route inside - gateway is a Hostname

Tags: cisco

- I have a cisco ASA-5505 configured to route internal network traffic "10.0.50.0/24 via tunnel - gateway IP is 68.150.169.32 with the following:

route inside 10.0.50.0 255.255.255.0 68.150.169.32 1

- I would need to configure the gateway using a Hostname "FQDN" as the hostname IP is always changing, when checked I found that route accepts Hostname:

---

## route inside 10.0.50.0 255.255.255.0 ?

configure mode commands/options:
  Hostname or A.B.C.D  The address of the gateway by which the foreign network
                       is reached.

### #

My problem is each time I add the hostname or any hostname like "host.cisco.com" I received the error --->  ERROR: % Invalid Hostname

- DNS is configured and I can ping any host, also created a object network for the hostname and fqdn but still receive the same error
- How to configure route using a hostname as a gateway, any examples?

Thanks.

Comment: Besides [Configuring the DNS Server](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/asa_84_cli_config/basic_hostname_pw.html#wp1080248), did you set the `dns-group` for the `tunnel-group`?

Comment: dns-group DefaultDNS is the only dns-group I have:

Comment: "_Specifies the DNS server group that the ASA uses for outgoing requests.
Other DNS server groups can be configured for VPN tunnel groups. See the **tunnel-group** command in the command reference for more information._"

Comment: Can you provide more details on how to configure DNS server group for VPN tunnel - there is a tunnel-group type ipsec-l2l - I'm not sure if I was clear - I want to change the gateway of the inside network 10.0.50.0/24 from the tunnel IP: 68.150.169.32  and replace it with a FQDN so it would be -> route inside 10.0.50.0 255.255.255.0  dns-remote.com   but when I do that I receive -> "ERROR: % Invalid Hostname"

Comment: Is that DNS name actually in the DNS server that you use? How does the DNS server update the address when it changes? You really need to edit your question to include the ASA configuration, and show what it is your are trying to change.

Comment: I have name-server configured on the ASA - 8.8.8.8, ... and the ASA is able to resolve and ping any hostname - > FW01# ping cisco.com
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 72.163.4.161, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 40/40/40 ms
FW01#

Comment: Right, but is the DNS name you wish to use instead of the IP address in that DNS server? Can you ping that name? You can't use a name unless it is in the DNS server. If the IP address changes, the DNS server needs to be updated with the new address for that name. How does that happen? It usually takes a while for DNS to get updated when things change.

Comment: When you mention "the DND server", you refer to the DNS server/service configured on the ASA or the DNS server/service that resolve the hostname I need to add - in both cases there is a DNS server "on the ASA" and remote dns server that change the IP of the hostname - yes, I can ping the hostname, the point is even if I use any hostname I receive the same error- even if I use cisco.com as a name instead of the gateway IP - my question is how it works, how to allow the ASA to use a name/hostname as a gateway instead of IP - better if you can provide an example/details

Comment: ASA says -> options: Hostname or A.B.C.D The address of the gateway by which the foreign network is reached. - I need to know how to use a Hostname

Comment: The host name and its IP address must be in the DNS server. Does the DNS server you use have that in it? All DNS does is look up the host name and return its IP address. IP only works with IP addresses, not names. DNS just allows you to use the name, which is easier to remember, but DNS needs to be able to resolve the name into an IP address.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter a hostname, it will be resolved on the spot and stored as the address to which it resolved at that point in time. You cannot route to a *dynamic* destination via a hostname. (in fact, that doesn't work on *ANY* platform) The only way to route to a moving target is via an active routing protocol (RIP, OSPF, etc.), or a scripted process (the way SLIP/PPP/DHCP are handled)

Comment: Alright, your logic make sense but forget about the fact that this hostname is changing IPs "consider it sticks with one IP", now can I use the hostname to create a static route via it  -  what makes me say this is a hostname option is valid in -> route inside... - so if it is valid as a static route option it would not probably need a dynamic routing protocol (RIP, OSPF,...)

Comment: How many ways can I say it? It does accept a hostname as valid input, however, *it is resolved **ONCE**, right then*. Do you expect it to lookup the address once per second and update the route table? That's the job of a dynamic routing protocol.

Comment: @RickyBeam A FQDN is resolved per the TTL provided by the DNS server, not once.  Enter `show dns` on the ASA to see the values.

Answer (score -1):

## [Cisco ASA Series Command Reference, A - H Commands](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa-command-reference/A-H/cmdref1/d3.html)

## [CLI Book 1: Cisco ASA Series General Operations CLI Configuration Guide, 9.5](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa95/configuration/general/asa-95-general-config/basic-hostname-pw.html)

#### poll-timer minutes number

The time, in minutes, of the polling cycle used to resolve FQDN network/host objects to IP addresses. FQDN objects are resolved only if they are used in a firewall policy. The timer determines the maximum time between resolutions; the DNS entry's time-to-live (TTL) value is also used to determine when to update to IP address resolution, so individual FQDNs might be resolved more frequently than the polling cycle. The default is 240 (four hours). The range is 1 to 65535 minutes.

#### dns expire-entry-timer

To remove the IP address of a resolved FQDN after its TTL expires, use the dns expire-entry-timer command in global configuration mode. To remove the timer, use the no form of this command.

```
dns expire-entry-timer minutes minutes

no dns expire-entry-timer minutes minutes
```

Syntax Description

```
minutes minutes
```

Specifies the timer time in minutes. Valid values range from 1 to 65535 minutes.

Defaults

By default, the DNS expire-entry-timer value is 1 minute.

If none of that works, look at EEM to maybe clear your DNS cache automatically, or something like that to force an update.

Comment: This has f*** all to do with a `route` entry -- and in fact, almost everywhere a hostname is accepted. I've explained exactly how this works. Get an ASA and try it yourself before spouting BS from the CLI guide. Also, 9.5 isn't supported on a 5505. (not that he's stated what version it's running.)

Comment: @RickyBeam You get angry every time I show you something new.  Why have that attitude?  You certainly must know that you have a lot to learn?  #1 [Configuring Objects 9.2 Supported on 5505](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa92/configuration/general/asa-general-cli/acl-objects.html?bookSearch=true#58870) #2 [Configuring Static Route Tracking via Object](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa72/configuration/guide/conf_gd/ip.html#wp1090243)

Comment: Because you are more often wrong than remotely on target, and you absolutely refuse to accept the reality of the universe we all live in. If you use a hostname in a route command, it will resolve *once*, right then, and store the address not the hostname. If you've ever used anything, you'd know this. The only way to make it work is via a script to re-insert the route when the dns name changes. (detecting that change is a different mess) Also note, all docs on `route` specify numbers not names.

Comment: Assuming the route add command on a ASA will not allow you to point to an object, why could you not route-map next-hop matching default to the object (the FQND)?  Also, IP SLA on PIX "The target can be any network object that you choose".  You're saying an [object](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa90/configuration/guide/asa_90_cli_config/acl_objects.html) cannot be used for routing purposes?  And, that "show dns" is unrelated to FQDN's in the ASA?